# What is considered as output when running a PHP script cron job?

Tags: php, email, cron

I am running a PHP script which inserts lines in a database every minute, using a cron job.

My provider says:

```
An email will be sent to this address ONLY if your cron produces output.
If no output is generated, then no email will be sent.
```

I am only issuing echo statements in my PHP when there is a query error. But I don't have errors, and I see the lines appearing in my DB.

Yet, I still get emails with (nearly) empty content even if I don't have errors:

```
Content-type: text/html
```

How can I prevent this? What is considered as output when running a PHP script cron job?

**UPDATE**

In order to get rid of the header, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723546/how-to-get-rid-of-content-type-text-html-in-php-script-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any calls to `header` in the code? Any whitespace outside of `<?php ... ?>` blocks? To answer your question 'output' is anything that would be sent to the browser in non-CLI operation, like that HTTP header you're seeing.

Comment: No call to header, but what do you mean by white spaces? There are some white spaces between my PHP instructions, but I don't echo or print any...

Comment: If you have something like this: `<?php dosomestuff(); ?>  <?php dosomethingelse(); ?>` the spaces between `?>` and `<?php` will be sent as output.

Comment: No, I don't. I only have one <?php ... ?>. I think I need to find how to remove that header...

Comment: Try removing the `?>` at the end of the file.

Comment: Just did, but it does not solve the issue

Comment: What's the full command passed to cron? Also -- make sure there's nothing before the opening `<?php`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3524/discussion-between-jverstry-and-xofer)